# debugging post variables with webkit

Tags: debugging, post, webkit

Webkit's Web Inspector is pretty nice, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to debug POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded variables in the requests. The "Query Parameters" palette shows up for GET requests, but nothing for POST. In fact, the only way I can see the request was indeed a POST is that the Request Headers have a Content-Type entry.

Is there a way, *in Webkit*, to show those variables? Such as a debugging plugin, a secret hidden preference, or simply being able to examine the content body being sent?

I'm aware that HTTP proxies such as Charles can be used here. I'd prefer to not use an additional tool if I can help it.

Comment: webkit's a browser rendering engine. it's not a browser in and of itself. you mean Safari? Chrome?

Comment: In this case yes, it's safari. The Web Inspector in Chrome is identical, though, so I'm assuming this is a feature of Webkit rather than either of the particular browser. I'm happy to be corrected, though :)